# postgres не связывается с образом приложения в docker

Tags: linux, debian, docker, spring-boot, docker-compose

При запуске на компьютере `docker-compose up` все прекрасно запускается и работает в связке.
Моя последовательность действий:

```
$docker build . -t myimage
$docker tag myimage:latest nik23225/myimage
$docker push nik23225/myimage
```

Теперь скачиваю и запускаю:

```
$docker pull nik23225/myimage
$docker run nik23225/myimage
```

В случае запуска через docker-compose(работает в директории с программой):

```
$docker-compose up
```

Но стоит мне запушить образ и скачать, а потом запустить его, происходит следующее:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
            at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:297) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar!/:42.2.14]
            at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar!/:42.2.14]
            at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:217) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar!/:42.2.14]
            at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:458) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar!/:42.2.14]
            at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:260) ~[postgresql-42.2.14.jar!/:42.2.14]
            at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
            at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
            at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
            at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:armv7l-centos-jdk-11.0.8_10
MAINTAINER experto.com
VOLUME /tmp
EXPOSE 8080
ADD target/testproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar testproject.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","testproject.jar"]
```

Docker-compose

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  app:
    container_name: app-springboot-postgresql
    image: app-springboot-postgresql
    build: ./
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - dbpostgres
  dbpostgres:
    image: postgres:9.6-alpine
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=mydb
```

Application properties

```
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=20000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=5
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://dbpostgres:5432/mydb
jwt.secret=nikita
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Запускаю на малинке и на пк изменяя образы jdk, postgres. Но проблема остается...

Comment: Как запускаете? При запуске через docker-compose также надо пробрасывать порты отдельным параметром.

Comment: Просто в консоли в директории проекта пишу docker-compose up, и все работает.

Comment: А после скачивания образа запускаю docker run 'image'

Comment: Попробуйте `docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 5432:5432 ...`

Comment: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.

Comment: Это сообщение докер при старте контейнера выдал? А порты свободны?

Comment: При старте прокручивается спринг, а потом он не находит соединения, я грешу на docker-compose, получается что один контейнер не видит другой, хотя оба запущены. Но никак не могу понять в чем хитрость(

Comment: Дополните вопрос, как вы `Но стоит мне запушить образ и скачать, а потом запустить его` - какие команды вы вводите, чтобы запустить. `docker run` НЕ использует docker-compose никаким боком. Нужны доп. параметры для `docker-run` - поэтому дополните вопрос, что вводите

Comment: Все, дополнил.)

Comment: docker-compose на самом деле делает много скрытой работы. Конкретно тут, он запускает два контейнера в одной сети. Вы же знаете, что контейнеры работают изолированно? Вот докер-композ помещает их в одну сеть. Если запускать контейнеры отдельно через docker run, они друг друга не смогут увидеть. Есть несколько вариантов, вот один: 1. запускаем оба контейнера 2. создаем сеть `docker network create app-network`. 3. Приаттачиваем оба контейнера к этой сети `docker network connect app-network первый-контейнер` и второй: `docker network connect app-network второй-контейнер`.

Comment: Все что я написал выше, довольно сложно сделать новичку. Поэтому лучше прочитать статьи как это работает. Например тут https://www.middlewareinventory.com/blog/docker-connect-containers-together/ со слов Method 2: Docker Network Connect Containers. Я в комменте выше делал через отдельную команду в шаге 3, а можно сначала создать сеть, и уже запускать контейнеры в ней через доп параметр `--network`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а можно ли применять docker-compose на скаченный образ на raspberry?

Comment: `можно ли применять docker-compose на скаченный образ на raspberry` - да, конечно. Нужно  заменить `image: app-springboot-postgresql` на `image: nik23225/myimage`.

Comment: Также есть команда `docker-compose build` - она дополнительно передает из композ-файла настройки, например окружение. Лучше использовать ее.

Comment: в `image:` правильное название впишите; чтоб удостовериться, что image свежий, можно менять ему имя (версию)